# Как выбрать нужную картину зависимости от времени

Tags: c++, время, arduino

Данный код выводит время 12:45

```
lv_img_set_src(ui_hour1, &ui_img_one_64_png);
lv_img_set_src(ui_hour2, &ui_img_two_64_png);
lv_label_set_text(ui_timeSep, ":");
lv_img_set_src(ui_minute1, &ui_img_four_64_png);
lv_img_set_src(ui_minute2, &ui_img_five_64_png);
```

Есть время `timeStringBuff` полученное так

```
struct tm timeinfo;
char timeStringBuff[50]; //50 chars should be enough
strftime(timeStringBuff, sizeof(timeStringBuff), "%H:%M", &timeinfo);
```

Как присвоить соответственные картинки соответственному времени?